# Install Hyper-V on Windows 8 PRO

Tags: windows-8, installation, hyper-v

I've tried to install Hyper-v platform component on my Windows 8 Pro. I got no message about anything going wrong. Just after "need restart" i got 30% progress done, then sudden restart again and "canceling unsuccessful install" message. No log messages, or rather say i don't know where to look for it. How could i install a Hyper-V server on W8PRO? which are the system requirements i need to check? 
I tried also recipe as advised for localized windows [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c2628f4a-5baf-449d-b53c-ef5f3ee8da3d/install-hyperv-on-windows-8-rtm-problem) it doesn't job on my W8PRO rus

UPDATE To Question: I 've also tried non-gui dism install of component that way i got the same result first a success message and rollback after reboot. there are a few warnings in dism.log
`DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName: Microsoft-Hyper-V`

> 2013-08-05 23:46:06, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE:
>   2013-08-05 23:46:17, Warning               DISM   DISM Provider Store:
>   PID=5636 TID=1280 Failed to Load the provider:
>   C:\Users\Yuri\AppData\Local\Temp\7A299A5C-6BD7-463C-83B7-E0C41ACF7C97\PEProvider.dll.
>   - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider(hr:0x8007007e)  2013-08-05 23:46:18, Warning               DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=5636
>   TID=1280 Failed to get the IDismObject Interface -
>   CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider(hr:0x80004002)   2013-08-05
>   23:46:18, Warning               DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=5636
>   TID=1280 Failed to Load the provider:
>   C:\Users\Yuri\AppData\Local\Temp\7A299A5C-6BD7-463C-83B7-E0C41ACF7C97\Wow64provider.dll.
>   - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider(hr:0x80004002)  2013-08-05 23:46:18, Warning               DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=5636
>   TID=1280 Failed to Load the provider:
>   C:\Users\Yuri\AppData\Local\Temp\7A299A5C-6BD7-463C-83B7-E0C41ACF7C97\EmbeddedProvider.dll.
>   - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider(hr:0x8007007e)

**I think these wornings are not a real cause of failure**

**UPDATE2**
executing dism  i go w/o any error up to this point

```
Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.2.9200.16384

Image Version: 6.2.9200.16384

Enabling feature(s)
The operation completed successfully.
Restart Windows to complete this operation.
Do you want to restart the computer now? (Y/N)
```

I collect all windows\logs\CBS\*.* plus i added a list of ALL enabled windows features

there is a [zip link](http://yadi.sk/d/nzF4uvzY7dG6U)
and raw texts [are here](http://yadi.sk/d/mbjEa3iK7dJlq)

Comment: Does your CPU support the required features for Hyper-V?  translate the Russian message in the screenshot and a post a screenshot of the error and translate that also post the log file.

Comment: Question updated.I have no error about system hardware, but minor warnings.

Comment: upload the folder C:\Windows\logs\CBS as zip to your skydrive, dropbox. I' ll take a look at the logs to see what fails.

Comment: Answer the CPU question please does your CPU support hyper-v

Comment: @Ramhound this is irrelevant for the issue. Without having the required CPU features the checkbox is disabled. When the configuration fails during reboot it is a Windows servicing issue were you must take a look at the log files.

Comment: @magicandre1981 - It might be irrelevant but I hate when people give me non-answers to questions I might have.  What is clear is the author's system integrity is comprmised if he is getting Wow64provider.dll errors.

Comment: The CPU has support of Hyper-V  http://ark.intel.com/products/53469

Comment: @Yurij73 The zip file you uploaded gives me CRC errors.

Comment: The only uncertain point that i do not have any remark of extended  pages mode in bios to enable|disable or Virtualization mode in bios may it be a bad symptom?

Comment: A link to folder with logs http://yadi.sk/d/mbjEa3iK7dJlq

Answer (score 1):

looks like updating the Boot Configuration Data (BCD) fails:

```
2013-08-06 20:19:56, Info                  CSI    00000025 Performing 1 operations; 1 are not lock/unlock and follow:
  (0)  LockComponentPath (10): flags: 0 comp: {l:16 b:d0395ccac092ce010a00000040044c04} pathid: {l:16 b:d0395ccac092ce010b00000040044c04} path: [l:238{119}]"\SystemRoot\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-hyper-v-drivers-hypervisor-bcd_31bf3856ad364e35_6.2.9200.16384_none_6e8b90a1724c0f3c" pid: 440 starttime: 130202795702002347 (0x01ce92c0ba94a2ab)
2013-08-06 20:19:56, Error                 CSI    00000026@2013/8/6:16:19:56.720 (F) base\boot\bcd\tools\bcdedit\ai\bcdeditai.cpp(455): Error HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(1006) originated in function Windows::WCP::BcdEdit::BasicInstaller::Uninstall expression: InnerStatus
[gle=0x80004005]
```

Error 1006 means this:

```
# for decimal 1006 / hex 0x3ee
  ERROR_FILE_INVALID                                             winerror.h
# The volume for a file has been externally altered so that
# the opened file is no longer valid.
```

Make sure the BCD is fine. You can use bootrec to rebuild the BCD:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392/en-us

Comment: tanks for this, tomorrow I will try rebuild bcd